# Which daily exercise are helpful to maintain health for long?

Tags: exercise

Which daily exercise are helpful to maintain health for long? And in what amount we need to do that? How much Yoga is helpful for physical and mental health?

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. I'm afraid that this question is too broad in its current state. You ask three separate question, and they are all pretty broad by themselves. If you can narrow this question down, please flag for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

For Yoga, [modern science says](http://www.artofliving.org/surya-namaskar-sun-salutation12-poses-leaner-you) do 54 sets = 108 reps of Surya Namaskar. Of course you need to [gradually build your stamina to increase reps](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/health-news/Whats-your-Surya-Namaskar-count/articleshow/5778365.cms).

My great-grandfather did 2 hours of yoga in morning, and lived to nearly 100 years. Also ate nuts, fruits, teas, water. This is according to my dad. Not [modern science](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/12/08/science-embraces-ancient-indian-wisdom_n_6250978.html), just things about family members that get passed down from generation to generation :-)

[According to American Health Association](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/PhysicalActivity/FitnessBasics/American-Heart-Association-Recommendations-for-Physical-Activity-in-Adults_UCM_307976_Article.jsp)

> AHA Recommendation
>
> For Overall Cardiovascular Health:
>
> At least 30 minutes of moderate-intensity aerobic activity at least 5
>   days per week for a total of 150
>
> OR At least 25 minutes of vigorous aerobic activity at least 3 days
>   per week for a total of 75 minutes; or a combination of moderate- and
>   vigorous-intensity aerobic activity
>
> AND Moderate- to high-intensity muscle-strengthening activity at least
>   2 days per week for additional health benefits.
>
> For Lowering Blood Pressure and Cholesterol An average 40 minutes of
>   moderate- to vigorous-intensity aerobic activity 3 or 4 times per week

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. I like the second source that you give, but the first two cannot really be backed up by science, which we [strongly encourage](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) on this site. Could you possibly add in sources to back up the yoga information you give?

Comment: @michaelpri Ok give me a few moments